# How to fill a join table with one SQL statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I have these tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    salary     INT,
    age        TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR(50),
    enabled    TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE roles
(
    id   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    role VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and also a join table between them

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_role
(
    user_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    role_id  INT         NOT NULL,
    role     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)
);
```

**How can I fill it with one SQL statement?**

Suppose, the `users` table has these values (the `id`s are generated automatically)

```sql
VALUES ('mickey_m', '$2y$10$i5SJc2KAriHGn7Dz2rRQHuQ3JfBxlzMaPVKP1YdEJCukryDY9NbVC',
        'Mickey', 'Mouse', 'sales', 180000, 95, 'mickey_m@gmail.com', 1),

       ('donald_d', '$2y$10$E6SHpAN0aZGQ43HAO.TPiO27kDKXOGIgDc8xWDJdl2Prn2wzQzz5y',
       'Donald', 'Duck', 'information technology', 190000, 89, 'donald_d@outlook.com', 1),

       ('scrooge_m', '$2a$10$ycVpl2BSD6o19wa3xXtmrOxc8qZjwoIk.e3oZqgQBOE.3NHANAYqa',
       'Scrooge', 'McDuck', 'board of directors', 700000, 76, 'scrooge@gmail.com', 1)
```

And suppose, I want everyone to have a `USER` role and `scrooge_m` to also have an `ADMIN` role. The join table should look something like this (plus `id`s that I may not know at the point of writing the SQL statement)

| user_id | username | role_id | role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | mickey_m |  | USER |
|  | donald_d |  | USER |
|  | scrooge_m |  | USER |
|  | scrooge_m |  | ADMIN |

My apparently bad attempt at it is below (I didn't test it, but it looks wrong – though, the IDE doesn't highlight anything here). I used `INSERT IGNORE` to reckon with the possibility that the rows may already be there

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role
WITH user_to_role(user, role) AS ( VALUES ROW('mickey_m', 'USER'),
                              ROW('donald_d', 'USER'),
                              ROW('scrooge_m', 'USER'),
                              ROW('scrooge_m', 'ADMIN')
SELECT users.id, users.username, roles.id, roles.role FROM users JOIN
    roles ON users.username = user_to_role.user AND roles.role = user_to_role.role;
```

When I [run it](https://dbfiddle.uk/MPv2CTxb) on *dbfiddle*, I get

```
Unknown column 'user_to_role.user' in 'on clause'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role (user_id, username, role_id, role)
SELECT u.id, u.username, r.id, r.role
FROM (
  VALUES
  ROW('mickey_m', 'USER'),
  ROW('donald_d', 'USER'),
  ROW('scrooge_m', 'USER'),
  ROW('scrooge_m', 'ADMIN')
) AS user_to_role (username, role)
JOIN users AS u ON u.username = user_to_role.username
JOIN roles AS r ON r.role = user_to_role.role;
```

Using aliases seems optional (I believe aliases are always optional). This works too:

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_role (user_id, username, role_id, role)
SELECT users.id, users.username, roles.id, roles.role
FROM (
         VALUES
             ROW('mickey_m', 'USER'),
             ROW('donald_d', 'USER'),
             ROW('scrooge_m', 'USER'),
             ROW('scrooge_m', 'ADMIN')
     ) AS user_to_role (username, role)
         JOIN users ON users.username = user_to_role.username
         JOIN roles ON roles.role = user_to_role.role;
```

You're still free to post your own solution.

The funny thing is my scripts don't seem to change the `NOT NULL` or `UNIQUE` properties of my columns. But that has probably to do with my `application.properties` and is no longer on topic. - [Sergey](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/272288/sergey)

Answer (score 1):

If the only things in `roles` are the id and role, get rid of the table.

Then, instead of discussion a many-to-many table, it is simply a 1:many table:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    user_id ...
    role VARCHAR ...
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, role),
    INDEX(role)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Do not include `username` in that table; (or your original `roles`), it is redundant.  Instead, use a `JOIN` whenever you need other columns.

When inserting into a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, do one row at a time so you can get the id:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, ...)
    VALUES
    ('mickey_m','...',  ', 'Mickey', 'Mouse', 'sales', 180000, 95, 'mickey_m@gmail.com', 1);
SELECT @lii := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO roles (user_id, role)
    VALUES
    (@lii, 'USER'),
    (@lii, 'HACKER');
```

Use `INSERT IGNORE` if you are likely to be re-inserting.  Use `UPDATE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for making changes without or with the option of also inserting.